# INNER JOIN DIM TABLE TO FOUND ID OF FIPS

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently trying to query the fips code and sum of the amount of cases for that code from the cases table and the id of the fips code for the subquery from the dim_counties table.
Here's what I have so far that has worked:

```
SELECT       DISTINCT C.FIPS,
             SUM(C.CASES) AS SUMS
FROM     DIM_DATE_MONTH B, CASES C
where 1=1
      and B.DATE_SHORT = SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(C.DAY_OF, 'MONTH'), 1,3)
      AND B.DATE_YR = SUBSTR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.DAY_OF),1,4)
      AND SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(C.DAY_OF, 'MONTH'), 1,3) = 'JAN'
      AND SUBSTR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.DAY_OF),1,4) = '2020'
GROUP BY C.FIPS
ORDER BY SUMS DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

What I have attempted that doesn't work

```
SELECT A.COUNTY_NBR,
       A.FIPS,
       D.SUMS
FROM DIM_COUNTIES A
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT     DISTINCT C.FIPS,
               SUM(C.CASES) AS SUMS
    FROM     DIM_DATE_MONTH B, CASES C
    where 1=1
      and B.DATE_SHORT = SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(C.DAY_OF, 'MONTH'), 1,3)
      AND B.DATE_YR = SUBSTR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.DAY_OF),1,4)
      AND SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(C.DAY_OF, 'MONTH'), 1,3) = 'JAN'
      AND SUBSTR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.DAY_OF),1,4) = '2020'
    GROUP BY C.FIPS
    ORDER BY SUMS DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)D ON D.SUM) D ON C.FIPS = A.FIPS;
```

Comment: This isn't mysql code... Are you seeking a mysql solution or is the question mistagged

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT with GROUP BY. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Please update your question to provide sample data for your source tables and the result you want to achieve based on that source sata